# Fastest way to create rows for a new data frame using loop for million of data

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, merging-data

I'm trying to create a new data set, using two indexes that are in both datasets respectively

it is taking longer time for 10k rows its taking 40min, can anyone help me what I must do to make it faster.

```
def Data_Set_Creation(df1,df2,df3):
    d={"match_data":[],
  "unmatch_data":[]}
    for j in range(df3.shape[0]):
        d["match_data"].append(df1[df1.CORE_CUSTOMER_ID==df3.CORE_CUSTOMER_ID_1.to_list()[j]].reset_index())
        d["unmatch_data"].append(df2[df2.CORE_CUSTOMER_ID==df3.CORE_CUSTOMER_ID_2.to_list()[j]].reset_index())

    df1=pd.DataFrame(d["match_data"])
    df2=pd.DataFrame(d["unmatch_data"])
    
    df_prob_match=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
        
    return df_prob_match
```

core_customer_id1 (df1) belongs to one dataset and core_customer_id2 belongs dataset 2(df2), i'm creating one row of data so that i can show both datasets in one row,

[image]

Comment: post the data, to make it reproducible    https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: if index are common then `df1 = pd.concat([df, df])` ; `df1.loc[df1.index.drop_duplicates(keep=False)]`

Comment: or `df1.loc[df1.groupby(level=0).size() > 1]`